# Создать PDF из таблицы SQLite3 с помощью библиотеки libharu

Tags: c, sqlite3, pdf

`report.c`

Параметр 2 (const char *text) — вывод из sql-запроса

```
HPDF_Page_ShowText (page, list()); // параметр 2 — вызов функции со sql-запросом из скрипта list.c, который должен возвращать const char *text
```

`list.c`

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libintl.h>

int list_cb_1(void *, int, char **, char **);

int list_cb_2(void *count, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    
    int *c = count;
    
    *c = atoi(argv[0]);
    
    return 0;
    
}

int list(void)
{

    sqlite3 *db;
    
    char *err_msg = 0;

    char sql[100];

    int count = 0;

    int rc = sqlite3_open("plants.db", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", 
        sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    sprintf(sql, "SELECT id, number, familia, taxon FROM numbers");

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, list_cb_1, 0, &err_msg);

    sprintf(sql, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers");

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, list_cb_2, &count, &err_msg);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK )
    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

        sqlite3_free(err_msg);
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Total Numbers: %d\n", count);

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;
}

int list_cb_1(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{

    NotUsed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {

        printf("%s\t ", argv[i]); // это нужно для вывода в консоль (если не предполагается создание отчёта в PDF)

        // здесь вывод для libharu для создания отчёта в PDF

    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```